# Question about LayoutHelper::render('joomla.html.image') and relative paths

Tags: images, htmlhelper

So Joomla 4 (ok 3 got it too) has this new way of handling images which is GREAT. But now i have to understand how it works because for a project i want to set a DIV's Background by using a field value.

$this->item->image contains a default joomla image construct

When I do the following:

```
<?php echo LayoutHelper::render('joomla.html.image', ['src' => $this->item->image, 'alt' => $this->item->title, 'class' => 'uk-cover']); ?>
```

it's got rendered as:

```
<img src="/path/to/image.jpg" ...>
```

Which is great, it adds the first forward slash! But i have to use the path inside a CSS background prop, so i checked the joomla.html.image layout but there is nothing in there which adds this forward slash.
Better: if i check the outcome inside the layout file (var_export) the displayData there is no slash in front...

When simply using:

```
$itemImage = HTMLHelper::_('cleanImageURL', $this->item->image);
$cleanImgUrl = $this->escape($itemImage->url);
```

...the forward slash is still missing and the image could not been loaded...

can someone please explain to me how to "magically" correct my image path too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slash is added by System - SEF plugin. It works by parsing the generated HTML markup and prepending Joomla root directory (or a slash if Joomla is not in a directory) in certain places like `src` and `href` attributes. It's possible that some valid cases are not yet covered by the plugin. These should be reported to developers.